# Avoid breaking inline math insertions

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

It is not a good idea to break mathematical insertions in text.

It happens in this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
dfasfsd asdfsdafds asdfsdfds gdsds sfsdd ssfsd  wwer sfdsf ggfh dh dgfdd $r=0.1$ sdfsd sdfdsf asgg sdfsdf a a sfsdf.
\end{document}
```

[image: ext]

How to do our best to preserve mathematical insertions on one line? Is there anything more handy than manually wrapping the troubled place in `mbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
dfasfsd asdfsdafds asdfsdfds gdsds sfsdd ssfsd wwer sfdsf ggfh dh
dgfdd $r=0.1$ sdfsd sdfdsf asgg sdfsdf a a sfsdf.

\bigskip

\begin{sloppypar}
\relpenalty=10000
dfasfsd asdfsdafds asdfsdfds gdsds sfsdd ssfsd wwer sfdsf ggfh dh
dgfdd $r=0.1$ sdfsd sdfdsf asgg sdfsdf a a sfsdf.
\end{sloppypar}


\end{document}
```

TeX only breaks after relations or binary operators, with penalty `\relpenalty` and `binoppenalty`, but as seen here in order not to break the math you need to excessively stretch the white space, and in this case no penalty less than the 10000 maximum value prevents a break.

Comment: will it work placing `\sloppy` and `\relpenalty=10000` in the preamble to avoid chasing down individual paragraphs?

Comment: @Viesturs yes, but the document will look horrible:-)

Comment: note that if you have inline math longer than a line it will not break if you set relpenalty and binoppenalty to 10000 so it will necessarily make an over full box @Viesturs